# Celery fakes autoreload

Tags: flask, celery

I'm using flask + celery, CELERY_IMPORTS are set correctly and it's all working, but when I made changes to a apps.dfp_ans.celery_tasks.get_report_data, celery says:

```
[2016-01-05 01:12:08,656: INFO/MainProcess] Detected modified modules: ['apps.dfp_ans.celery_tasks.get_report_data']
```

But nothing happens. It still uses the old code.
When I Ctrl+C and restart celery, then it works as it should.
What is the root of the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. Celery does not automatically reload modules that are updated on disk.

Comment: So, it only says in console that it was updated? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: to let you know that there is a mismatch between the code on disk and what is currently running.